# Extract PDF front page and store it as an image field in node

Tags: media, files, entities

I'm using [Document Library module](https://www.drupal.org/project/document_library) to manage my files and create listings for them.

I've also noticed the existence of [PDFPreview module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdfpreview) and I'd like to ask if the following is possible:

I'd like to upload a pdf file in a Document Library Document item and with this file to generate an preview image, **stored as a new independent field (lets say the Thumbnail image field) in this content type**. As things are now the preview replaces the file field which is something that I need to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I just realized that another module, the [PDF to Image Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_to_imagefield) module does exactly what I need! Some more details about thsi module (from its project page):

> The PDF To ImageField module provides automatic conversion of uploaded PDF files to images. It can be used either to create a snapshot of the front page to use as a preview thumbnail, or to generate a gallery of images from each page in the document.
>
> The module is implemented as an additional widget for File Field where PDFs are uploaded to. It places generated images into a Image Field on the same content type.

At least, I hope this helps other people too.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know you could do this, so it did "help" me ... BTW: hope you'd agree with my edit I just applied, to make it look less like a "link only" answer (which puts such answers at risk of being deleted). If you don't like my edit (or phrasing), rework it as you would want it to look like, ok?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Its fine. Glad to help & thanks for time!